# Integrating the content of column vertically in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
  personID             activityPurpose
  2_BRUResident            home
  2_BRUResident            work
  2_BRUResident        shopping
  2_BRUResident         leisure
  2_BRUResident            home
  3_BRUResident            home
  3_BRUResident            work
  4_BRUResident            home
  4_BRUResident            work
  4_BRUResident        shopping
  4_BRUResident        shopping
  4_BRUResident            home
  4_BRUResident         leisure
  4_BRUResident            work
  4_BRUResident            home
```

It represents the activity records of different persons. What I want to have now is an overview of each people's activity chain, something like below:

```
  personID             activityChain
  2_BRUResident        home-work-shopping-leisure-home
  3_BRUResident        home-work
  4_BRUResident        home-work-shopping-shopping-home-leisure-work-home
```

I am wondering how should I achieve this in R? Thanks in advance!

Below is the code for reprex:

```
test <- data.frame(personID = c("2_BRUResident", "2_BRUResident", 
                                "2_BRUResident", "2_BRUResident", "2_BRUResident", "3_BRUResident", 
                                "3_BRUResident", "4_BRUResident", "4_BRUResident", "4_BRUResident", 
                                "4_BRUResident", "4_BRUResident", "4_BRUResident", "4_BRUResident", 
                                "4_BRUResident"), activityPurpose = c("home", "work", "shopping", 
                                                                      "leisure", "home", "home", "work", "home", "work", "shopping", 
                                                                      "shopping", "home", "leisure", "work", "home"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

test |>
  group_by(personID) |>
  summarize(activityChain = paste(activityPurpose, collapse = "-"))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  personID      activityChain                                     
  <chr>         <chr>                                             
1 2_BRUResident home-work-shopping-leisure-home                   
2 3_BRUResident home-work                                         
3 4_BRUResident home-work-shopping-shopping-home-leisure-work-home
```